# Integral of a function $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, complex-analysis, derivatives

My real analysis book defines derivatives and integrals only for a function $f:A\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, where $A\subset \mathbb{R}$. But, when talking about Fourier series, it comes out an integral like $\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} e^{inx}dx$. What does it mean? What is the definition of derivative and integral of a function $f:A\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$, where $A\subset \mathbb{R}$ ? (Please motivate the definition) Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

It may help to know that $e^{inx}=\cos nx+i\sin nx$ now let us apply the fact that if $f:\mathbb R\to \mathbb C$, $f(x)=g(x)+ih(x)$, when we do our integral, we take the imaginary bit out side of the integral so we can just use real integral theory.
 We apply it as follows:

$\displaystyle\qquad \int f(x)\,dx= \int \operatorname{Re}(f(x))\,dx + i\int \operatorname{Im}(f(x))\,dx. $

In the context of your question we have:

$\displaystyle\qquad
  \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} e^{inx} \,dx 
= \int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\cos nx+i\sin nx \,dx
= \int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\cos nx\,dx+i \int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\sin nx\,dx
= 0$.

Answer (score 1):

As long as the independent variable is real (i.e., neither complex nor vector valued) then the usual definitions carry over to complex or vector valued functions, and standard properties of limits then imply that the derivative, or the integral, is a complex number (vector) whose real and imaginary parts (components) are the derivatives, or the integral, of the corresponding parts.

To be more explicit: When $f(t)=u(t)+i v(t)$ is complex valued then

$$f'(t):=\lim_{h\to 0}{f(t+h)-f(t)\over h}=\lim_{h\to 0}{u(t+h)-u(t)\over h}+i \>\lim_{h\to 0}{v(t+h)-v(t)\over h}=u'(t)+i v'(t)\ ,$$
$$\eqalign{\int_a^b f(t)\>dt&:=\lim_\ldots\ \sum_{k=1}^Nf(\tau_k)(t_k-t_{k-1})=\lim_\ldots\ \sum_{k=1}^N\bigl(u(\tau_k)+iv(\tau_k)\bigr)(t_k-t_{k-1})\cr
&=\int_a^b u(t)\>dt + i\int_a^b v(t)\>dt\ .\cr}$$

Answer (score 0):

When you have a function $f: R \to C$, for each $x \in R$ you can write $f(x)$ as a sum $a + bi$. If we define  $g(x) = a$ and $h(x) = b$, and repeat this for every $x$, we get new functions $g$ and $h$ from $R \to R$. We integrate $f$ by integrating each part, so

$$
\int_0^\pi f(x) dx = \int_0^\pi g(x) dx + i \int_0^\pi h(x) dx,
$$
with the motivation being that when we have two components, the usual thing to do is deal with them component-wise. :)

Answer (score 0):

Imagine we are in $\mathbb R^3$ but the $y$ and $z$ axis actually belong to the complex plane, so we are actually in $\mathbb C \times    \mathbb R$. The function $f(x)=e^{ix}$ defines an helix with its axis aligned with the $x$ axis. The integral of $f$ with respect to $x$ is the 'directed' area between that helix and the $x$ axis.
I say directed because it's the area along with it's complex sign. Just like when you integrate $sin(x)$ between $0$ and $2\pi$, you get $0$ because you take into account the sign of the area.
Likewise if you integrate $f(x)$ between $0$ and $2\pi$ you will get $0$ because you have the same amount of area pointing in every direction of the $\mathbb C$ plane, there is rotational symmetry.

In general, I think most of us don't think about complex analysis in geometrical terms, we just take the definitions and use the theorems arising from them, working in a purely formal way.